# How to use Popen to run backgroud process and avoid zombie?

Tags: python, process, subprocess, zombie-process

I've a listener server running new thread to for each client handler. Each handler can use:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(argv, executable = "./Main.py", stdout = _stdout, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=False)
```

to run new process in background, after what the handler thread is ended.

After the background process is ended, it is kept in Z state. Is it possible to ask subprocess.Popen() to handle SIG_CHILD to avoid this zombie?

I don't want to read process state using proc.wait(), since for this I've to save the list of all running background processes...

**UPD**

I need  to run some processes in background avoiding zombies and to run some processes with .communicate() to read data from these processes. In that case using signal trick from **koblas** I get an error:

```
File "./PyZWServer.py", line 115, in IsRunning
  return (subprocess.Popen(["pgrep", "-c", "-x", name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0] == "0")
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 698, in communicate
  self.wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1170, in wait
  pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 465, in _eintr_retry_call
   return func(*args)
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
Error happened during handling of client
```

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something unintentionally, but I don't understand the logic of the last sentence. Why does "I've to save the list of all running background processes" cause "I don't want to read the process state using proc.wait()"?

Comment: I've edited this sentence. I have to save this list if I want to read state, but I don't need the state and don't want to save this list only to read state...

Comment: Oh, ok. I read it as "I already am saving the state, so I don't want to use proc.wait()" I get it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a signal handler for SIGCHLD you will have the kernel handle the wait/reap piece.

Specifically the line:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

Will take care of your Zombies.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but for all processes. And how to do the same only for some processes? I need  to run some processes in background avoiding zombies and to run some processes with .communicate() to read data from these processes. In that case I get an error. see update of the question.

Comment: In playing around with this, the challenge is that communicate() assumes a bunch of behaviors.  If you wrap your own Popen and construct a signal handler the communcicate() can abort with an interrupted read call due the the SIGCHLD signal being deliverd (it doesn't retry).  So the "right" fix is for you to have your own version of Popen that does what you need..  The other choice is for processes that you don't want to Zombie you need to double wrap them such that you can reap a parent and let a subchild run along on it's own.

Comment: brilliant answer! have been struggling for ages to take care of the children without using direct references to Popen instances